# Trying to build a new mobile project in unity 2D Mobile Core when trying to build both Build & Build And Run buttons disabled gray how to fix?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using Unity version 2021.3.27f1 Personal

This are the steps I did:

After created the project I clicked the File > Build Settings... menu.

In the opened window I clicked on Android on the left side, it was grayed out, I saw the message No Android module loaded Install with Unity Hub, when clicking the button, I installed the Android Build Support > OpenJDK and Android SDK & NDK Tools.

After installed finished both buttons still grayed out and I clicked Switch Platform, and it did work but, in the end, both buttons are still greyed out and I also got an error:

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.6.6\Editor\BurstAotCompiler.cs(754,27): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AndroidExternalToolsSettings' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor.Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Then double click on the error and in visual studio the error seems to be on this line:

`ndkRoot = UnityEditor.Android.AndroidExternalToolsSettings.ndkRootPath;`

line 754 in the file BurstAotCompiler.cs

Here is a screenshot of the editor.  I have already installed visual studio 2022 personal, so I didn't install the 2019 version:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LckOy.jpg)

I tried to google but didn't find any clean 100% working solution so far.
I found that some ppl deleted libraries or folders but not a real solution.

Comment: Does this help? https://forum.unity.com/threads/the-type-or-namespace-name-androidexternaltoolssettings-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-unityedit.1288067/

Comment: @MrDiamond yes that solves this error and now both buttons enabled but when clicking the Build button or the Build And Run it's trying to compile and in the end it's showing a message with 4 errors : https://imgur.com/a/UUqWOk3 I have no clue what are all this errors.

Comment: Do not warp one question into another. Make a new question